# honda hornet 2005 cb600 high gasoline consumption

Tags: engine, motorcycle, fuel-system, hornet

hi my hornet Consumed abut 1 liter for 10 kilo i have iridium spark plug and k&n air filter and modified exhaust i cleaned carburetor and still have this problem

Comment: So, you seem to be making mods for more power then worry about using more fuel... What did you expect?

Comment: What is your riding style? If I ride hard I can get mileage approaching that.

Comment: i didn't make those i bought the bike like this so i asked is all of those make that problem